# Changing The names in the abaqus using python

Tags: python, composite, sections, abaqus

I want to define a new name for every section and section assignment by defining a loop in python.

```
for i in range(numberofgrain):
    mysection = myModel.HomogeneousSolidSection(
                  material='Composite',
                  name=mySection[i],
                  thickness=None)
```

for example mySection1, mySection2,...for different parts of the model. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean `name=mySection[i]`?

Comment: yes, I mean name=mySection[i] in order to have mySection[1], mySection[2],... for different part in the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know Abaqus, but it looks like your syntax should be

```
mysection = []
for i in range(numberofgrain):
    mysection.append(myModel.HomogeneousSolidSection(name='mySection[{}]'.format(i), material='Composite', thickness=None))
```

or, if you are feeling adventurous,

```
mysection = [myModel.HomogeneousSolidSection(name='mySection[{}]'.format(i), material='Composite', thickness=None) for i in range(numberofgrain)]
```

**Edit:** - patched updating of mySection[i] names.

Comment: +note for older python versions you may need `'mySection[{0}]'`

Comment: Thank you very much @Hugh Bothwell. it is working very well.

Comment: @MojENG *nudge* If it solved your problem, you should click on the checkmark next to this answer to make it official.